# save div to image (not working)

Tags: jquery, html, image, canvas

I got one code from fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/) for converting div into image.'
but when i am trying to implement in my page its not working.. 
Below is my code....

Plz help me friends.......

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
       html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="widget" class="widget">  
    this is text.
</span>
<br/>
<button id="btnSave">Save PNG</button>

<div id="img-out"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have jquery core included. You would need the additional js files included in your project.

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/base64.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/canvas2image.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks now its working.... but in fiddle .. they dint include any file.... so i thought it will work without adding extra files

Comment: The fiddle does included them. Over on the left look for 'external resources' this will list any external resources with css files or js files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the libraries correctly? On your code you only load jquery file.